# how to fix node js error while using bitbucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

Im trying to use a bitbucket code which i have imported into Vscode and make the server listen on port 3000 using MSSQL database to get. After which i have to implement the endpoint. I just would like to know i installed all packages and also dependences why im i still geting the same error. where i have install npm expree and all in same env i feel. PLease help me with this.

npm install express
npm install express-session
npm install mssql

'use strict';

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const Database = require('./lib/Database');

const setup = async () => {
  const database = new Database();
  const db = await database.init()
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
      });

  const app = express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

  app.get('/devices', (req, res, next) => {
    return db.all('SELECT * FROM devices;')
        .then((devices) => res.json(devices))
        .catch(next);
  });

  app.get('/devices/:deviceId', (req, res, next) => {
    return db.get('SELECT * FROM devices WHERE id = ?;', req.params.deviceId)
        .then((devices) => res.json(devices))
        .catch(next);
  });

  app.post('/devices', (req, res, next) => {
    const newDevice = [req.body.siteId, req.body.name, req.body.active];
    return db.run('INSERT INTO devices (siteId, name, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', newDevice)
        .then((insertResult) => db.get('SELECT * FROM devices WHERE id = ?', insertResult.stmt.lastID))
        .then((insertedDevice) => res.json(insertedDevice))
        .catch(next);
  });

  app
      .listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
        console.info('server listening on port: 3000');
      })
      .on('request', (req) => {
        console.info(req.method, req.baseUrl + req.url);
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
};

setup();
```

I want to make the port listen using node and also implement functionalities of CRUD operations.

Error is Occur as below

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'c:\Users\me\Downloads\nodeAPI\migrations']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'c:\Users\me\Downloads\nodeAPI\migrations' }

Comment: You shouldn't install libraries manually. The `package.json` is there to avoid this. You should use `npm install`. What is the error you get ?

Comment: Thanaks, But i already have installed spm packages, can you give me more details to this please ?

Comment: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'c:\Users\me\Downloads\nodeAPI\migrations'] errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'scandir', path: 'c:\Users\me\Downloads\nodeAPI\migrations' } @Weedzoe

Comment: Are you sure that you installed packages in the project directory?

Comment: hi thanks @Konowy there was issue with the npm packages which i installed it in wrong dictionary. Thanks for the help and time .

Answer (score 0):

For someone who would encounter similar problem.

1. Always make sure that you are in the project root directory (there should be `package.json` there).
2. Use `npm install` or `yarn install` to install the packages (don't do it by hand).